# Валидация даты из будущего AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

Есть поле с датой,сейчас валидация на формат срабатывает,если указать день больше 31 и месяц больше 12. Можно ли сделать,чтобы валидация так же срабатывала если введенная даты больше сегодняшней?
Вот мой код:

```
<div class="col-md-4">
    <p class="input-group">
        <input name="regCard_IdentifyingDocument_WhenIssued"
            type="text" class="input-field__element"
            style="border-right: none "
            uib-datepicker-popup="ddMMyyyy"
            ui_mask="99.99.9999"
            show-button-bar="false"
            on-open-focus="false"
            ng-model="prod.RegCard.IdentifyingDocument.WhenIssued"
            is-open="datepickerWhenIssuedOpened"
            datepicker-options="{showWeeks:false}"
            alt-input-formats="altInputFormats"
            required/>
        <span class="input-group-btn">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary choose-address-btn" ng-click="datepickerWhenIssuedOpened = true"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i></button>
        </span>
    </p>
</div>
<div class="col-md-4">
    <div ng-messages="regCardForm.regCard_IdentifyingDocument_WhenIssued.$error" ng-if="regCardForm.regCard_IdentifyingDocument_WhenIssued.$dirty || regCardForm.$submitted || regCardForm.regCard_IdentifyingDocument_WhenIssued.$touched" class="help-block" role="alert">
         <div ng-message="required" class="text-danger">Обязательное поле</div>
         <div ng-message="date" class="text-danger">Неправильная дата</div>
     </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

В опциях добавьте:

```
datepicker-options="{showWeeks:false, maxDate: new Date()}"
```

Comment: Это первое что я попробовал согласно документации, но в этом случае у меня почему то ломается вся форма и при нажатии на календарь пикер вообще не открывается
<https://ibb.co/MnFRnn7>

Comment: причем даже если протащить переменную с текущей датой из контроллера
maxDate:{{maxDate}}
все равно аналогично.

Comment: если с контроллера то maxDate: maxDate (без двойных кавычек)

Comment: в таком случае все нормально,пикер открывается,но даты не заблокированы.

Answer (score 0):

alt-input-formats="altInputFormats" ссылался на отсутствующую переменную, и при добавлении опции maxDate почему то все ломалось. Проблема решилась удалением этой строчки из кода.